# java hibernate query.list returns empty list

Tags: java, hibernate, jpql

I am using hibernate with JPA annotations and Jboss transaction manager I build the session factory open up a session and create a query when i use query.list it always returns me an empty list

any idea?

Comment: show the source; check the query returns data

Comment: Check the generated SQL, make sure your query **should** return any data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Few suggestions:**

Enable configuration parameter `show-sql` in `persistence.xml`. Try this, i.e.

```
<property name="hibernate.show.sql" value="true" />
```

Furthermore, it is better to format that using,

```
<property name="hibernate.format_sql" value="true" />
```

And then try to run the same query in some SQL Client.

Comment: no query is printed   <property name="show_sql">true</property>

Comment: @slimshady: I modified the answer to include the property configuration. Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

If you are adding values in the database from the command prompt manually, perform the commit operation after insertion. especially in oracle DB