# Display values retrieved from database in a table

Tags: java, sql, hibernate, foreach, controller

I am quite new to hibernate frameworks and I am working on a Hibernate framework project in the netbeans IDE. I have a javadb that is connected to the project and I need to get the task list for each employee and display it as a bullet list in a `<td>` against each employee name. The following is the table displaying the employees' names and roles that are being fetched using the `getEmployeeDetails` method in the EmployeeHelper class.

> Issue
>  - The task list is always empty though I call the `resultTaskList` parameter that is passed from the Controller.
>  - I know that I have to do an if conditional check for task within the nested forloop that will list the tasks to group them based on the employee names. But am not sure how to do an `if` within a jsp page.

*Any suggestions on how to display the task list of each employee within the same table will be highly appreciated.*

In this table, I intend to have the tasks pertaining to each employee as a bulletlist within each corresponding `<td>`.

[image: Table]

**Employee.jsp**

```
...
<div class="content">
<!--Display table of roles with an edit button against each role-->
<form method="get" action="<%= request.getContextPath() %>/RoleController">
    <br>

    <table border ="2">
        <thead class="thead-inverse">
            <tr>
              <th></th>
              <th>Employee Name</th>
              <th>Role</th>
              <th>Tasks</th>
              <th>Edit</th>
            </tr>
          </thead>
          <tbody>
            <c:forEach items="${result}" var="res">
                <tr>
                    <th scope="row">
                    </th>
                    <td>
                        <c:out value="${res[0]}"></c:out>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <c:out value="${res[1]}"></c:out>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <c:out value="${resultTaskList[1]}"></c:out>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <input type="button" class="btn btn-info" value="Edit Role">
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </c:forEach>
    </table>
</form>
</div>
...
```

**EmployeeController.java**

```
protected void processRequest(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws ServletException, IOException {
    EmployeeHelper helper = new EmployeeHelper();
    List<Employee> resultTaskList = helper.getEmployeeTasks();
    request.setAttribute("resultTaskList", resultTaskList);
    List<Employee> result = helper.getEmployeeDetails();
    request.setAttribute("result", result);
    request.getRequestDispatcher("Employee.jsp").forward(request, response);
}
```

**EmployeeHelper.java**

```
public class EmployeeHelper {
    Session session = null;

    public EmployeeHelper(){
        this.session = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().openSession();
    }


    public List getEmployeeDetails(){
        Transaction tx = this.session.beginTransaction();

        List<Employee> employeeList = null;

        try{
            Query query = session.createQuery("select e.name, r.title from Employee as e, Role as r where e.employeeid=r.employeeid");
            employeeList = (List<Employee>)query.list();
            tx.commit();
        }
        catch(HibernateException ex){
            ex.printStackTrace();
            tx.rollback();
        }
        return employeeList;
    }

    public List getEmployeeTasks(){
        Transaction tx = this.session.beginTransaction();

        List<Employee> employeeTaskList = null;

        try{
            Query query = session.createQuery("select e.name, t.description from Employee as e, Role as r, Task as t, EmployeeTask as et where e.employeeid=r.employeeid and t.taskid=et.taskid and e.employeeid=et.employeeid");
            employeeTaskList = (List<Employee>)query.list();
            tx.commit();
        }
        catch(HibernateException ex){
            ex.printStackTrace();
            tx.rollback();
        }
        return employeeTaskList;
    }
}
```

**SQL Query executed within the `getEmployeeTasks()` method**

[image]

Comment: You need to create a result that is a List that holds an object that contains both the Employee information **and** the tasks.  At the moment you have two unrelated lists

Comment: You're completely missing the point of Hibernate, which is to map the relational database to an object model, with associations (rather than IDs) between entities. Your query should just retrieved employees, and the JSP should display employee.name, employee.role.title, and iterate over employee.tasks to display the description of each task of the employee. Employee should thus has a ManyToOne association with Role, and a OneToMany or ManyToMany association with Task.

Comment: I am quite new to hibernate. So could you kindly provide an answer sample on where I am going wrong exactly. Thanks in advance

Comment: Everything is already in my comment. Now you need to start reading a book, or simply the user manual of Hibernate to start learning about associations. https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/current/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#associations

Answer (score 1, accepted):

instead of  List employeeTaskList use  List and iterate loop and set values in employee list try following code .

```
   public List getEmployeeTasks(){

    Transaction tx = this.session.beginTransaction();

    List<Employee> employeeTaskList = null;

    try{
       session.beginTransaction();
      Query query = session.createQuery("select e.name, t.description from Employee as e, Role as r, Task as t, EmployeeTask as et where e.employeeid=r.employeeid and t.taskid=et.taskid and e.employeeid=et.employeeid");
        List<Object[]> result = (List<Object[]>) query.list();

    if (null != result && result.size() != 0) {

            for (Object[] obj : result) {
                //Set values over here 
                employeeTaskList.set.....
            }
        tx.commit();
    }
    }
    catch(HibernateException ex){
        ex.printStackTrace();
        tx.rollback();
    }
    return employeeTaskList;
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the reply Tejal. But since the `<td>` is dynamically created based on the first list, how am I supposed to do `employeeTaskList.set...` here?

Comment: create Employee emp=new Employee() in above for loop and set values in object and add it into employeeTaskList

Answer (score 0):

These two lists are non-related as suggested by *JB Nizet*. Still You can do something like this.

```
        <c:forEach items="${result}" var="res">
            <tr>
                <th scope="row">
                </th>
                <td>
                    <c:out value="${res[0]}"></c:out>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <c:out value="${res[1]}"></c:out>
                </td>
                <td>
                <c:forEach items="${resultTaskList}" var="resultTaskList">
                    <c:if test = "${res[0] == resultTaskList[0]}">
                    <c:out value="${resultTaskList[1]}"></c:out>
                    </c:if>
                </c:forEach>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <input type="button" class="btn btn-info" value="Edit Role">
                </td>
            </tr>
        </c:forEach>
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks Akshay. This is exactly what I want to do and I can see that this should work. But when I tried this, am not getting any tasks displayed. So I tried testing the number of results returned by the `resultTaskList` and it's 0. Since the query worked when run as sql, I am unable to find a reason why it's not working for this. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Look at this answer and check if you are using correct drivers. 
     https://stackoverflow.com/a/6841177/3270795